# SQL Select XML nodes, parametrize node number

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, sql-server-2008-r2, sqlxml

I'm selecting data from a XML document, however I need to loop through each child node perform some actions on them.

At present I have a while exists loop around the select but don't know how to parametrize the node number.

I understand the below isn't right but would appreciate it if someone could point out the best way to parametrize the node selection.

Thanks.

```
DECLARE @nodeCount varchar(1) = '1'
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT table.value('(Info/Data/DataInfo/Type/node())[' + @nodeCount + ']', 'nvarchar(10)') from table)
```

The XML is as follows:

```
<Info xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<Data>
<DataInfo>
  <Description>11111111111</Description>     
  <Type>1</Type>
</DataInfo>
<DataInfo>
  <Description>2222222222222</Description>     
  <Type>2</Type>
</DataInfo>
<DataInfo>
  <Description>3333333333333</Description>    
  <Type>3</Type>
</DataInfo>
</Data>
</Info>
```

Comment: Can you show us a sample of that XML? What does it look like, and what are you trying to do on those XML nodes?

Comment: The XML has been posted above. I simply need a way to obtain the data from each node individually. I can select a node by passing in the number but need to make it dynamic.

Comment: Can you use something like `table.nodes('/Info/Data/DataInfo')` and iterate over that list of XML nodes you get back?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get all data by one query with [nodes()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188282.aspx) function:

```
select
    t.c.value('(text())[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') as [Type]
from @xml.nodes('/Info/Data/DataInfo/Type') as t(c)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22101)</kbd>**

Or, if you really want to loop, you can use [sql:variable()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188254.aspx) extension function:

```
DECLARE @nodeCount int = 1
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT table.value('(Info/Data/DataInfo/Type/node())[sql:variable("@nodeCount")][1]', 'nvarchar(10)') from table)
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/22102)</kbd>**