# updating part of SQL field

Tags: sql

I have 4900 rows in a sql table that I need to update part of it on.

The end date is what I need to change but the create date is unique

example

```
<ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
     <PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="StartDatePromotionRule">
          <StartDate>
             2010-11-19T13:44:15.253
          </StartDate>
     </PromotionRuleBase>
     <PromotionRuleBase xsi:type="ExpirationDatePromotionRule">
          <ExpirationDate>
              2014-01-01T00:00:00
          </ExpirationDate>
     </PromotionRuleBase>
 </ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase>
```

How can I change all with just the Expiration date part?

Comment: What's the column data type? Is it xml?

Comment: Take a look at sql XPath. I don't want to answer as I've not used it in a LONG time but I believe that's your best route.

Comment: hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19158537/sql-select-xml-nodes-parametrize-node-number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you have a field that contains XML and you only want to change a portion of it. I don't think SQL has any tools to edit XML. You will have to write code in your application that does XML parsing and change it from there. However, that could be quite an expensive operation. If you can guaranty that ExpidationDate will only contain the time, you could use a regex to replace it.

This regex captures the date in group1. You can then do a simple replace:

```
<ExpirationDate.*>\s*(.*)\s*</ExpirationDate>
```

Comment: Ended up using something along the lines of this which seem to work fine update Promotions
set PromotionRuleData.modify('declare namespace ns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";replace value of (/ArrayOfPromotionRuleBase//ExpirationDate/text())[1] with "2015-01-01T00:00:00"')
where ID=2